# What is the physical meaning behind a meter (long) x a meter (long)?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units

I have searched the internet for an answer to this question, but nothing satisfactory comes up.  I have been told that a meter x a meter always equals to a square meter, but I have decided this cannot always be the case.

A meter lengthwise multiplied into a meter widthwise will undoubtedly form a square, each of sides one meter.

But, what happens when you multiply a meter lengthwise times a meter lengthwise?

What I was taught, that it differs in no way from a square meter, poses some obvious issues.  The most obvious one being that the units of torque are unequal in value to the units of energy.  We are correctly taught as physics students to handle them differently; torque has units kg*m(lw)*m(ww)/s^2, whereas energy has units kg*m(lw)^2/s^2, where lw means lengthwise and ww means widthwise.  The former requiring two dimensional analysis, the latter only one.

In my search, I have also come across the notion that physical units need not physical consequence.  That they need only to work out in the mathematical sense.  Of course, this directly contradicts an axiom of physics, that is the subject deals with physical meaning!

So, i ask again, what is the physical meaning of a meter lengthwise x a meter lengthwise?

Comment: In what context are you multiplying a "meter lengthwise" by itself?

Comment: If you want to think about multiplying lengths in a way that their directions matter, Google "dot product" and "cross product". The result of multiplying two vectors with the same direction is very different between these two operations, and which operation you should use depends on why you are multiplying your two vectors (lengths or displacements in your example)

Comment: @The Photon Energy has a m^2 component (though these units both represent length), while torque has a m-length x m-width component.  I can conceptualize m-length x m-width.  This forms a square, but i struggling to conceptualize a m-length x m-length.

Comment: Cross product only works in 3D and even there the result is a pseudovector. In 4D you use wedge product and the result is a bivector. https://tok.fandom.com/wiki/Multivectors

Comment: I am grateful for the link, i will read up on it!

Answer (score 3):

> [...] the units of torque are unequal in value to the units of energy.

That is not correct.  Torque and energy are measured in dimensionally equivalent units. The reason we usually quote torque in something like newton-meters and energy in joules is that we want to remind ourselves that torque and energy are different concepts, **despite** sharing the same dimensions. The fact that torque and energy are completely different quantities which have the same units should be an indicator that units don't tell the whole story.

I fear your question doesn't really make sense to me.  You talk about multiplying a meter by a meter, but I don't know what that means.  If I hand you two meter sticks and tell you to multiply them together, what would you do?  The SI base unit of energy is equivalent to $\frac{\text{kg m}^2}{\text{s}^2}$, but that m$^2$ in the numerator has nothing to do with area, as you appear to believe.

In general, units don't tell you very much all by themselves.  For example, if I asked you for the physical significant of the unit kg/s$^2$, what would you say?  Perhaps there's some reservoir being drained via some pipe, and the rate at which water is flowing through the pipe is quoted in kilograms (of water) per second; the rate at which this rate is changing would then be measured in kg/s$^2$.

On the other hand, kg/s$^2$ is also the SI base unit associated to the spring constant which appears in Hooke's law.  Of course, you're likely more accustomed to seeing that quoted in newtons per meter, but since a newton is a kg m/s$^2$, those are the same units.

At the end of the day, physical quantities have units, but units all by themselves don't have any physical meaning until you know the quantity to which they refer.

Comment: Perhaps i do have a misunderstanding.  Let me explain.  If i hand you a meter stick, and ask you to find the length of a table, you can easily do this.  But, if i were to ask you to find the width of the same table, you must turn the meter stick, relative to the table, in order to measure this new quantity.  It is a subtle change in units, meter-length vs. meter-width, but it is a change nonetheless.  Thus, torque, which deals with units of meter-length and meter-width, has different units than energy, which deals with meter-length alone.

Comment: @MouazNachawati It's not a new quantity.  If I asked you to measure the length of one table, and then the length of a different table, you'd *also* have to move the meter stick - am I to understand that those lengths are different as well, just because I had to physically move the measurement tool?  What if I moved the table and kept the meter stick where it was?

Comment: But, you bring up another interesting unit, the s^2.  It surely must be a misnomer that we say seconds sqaured, because under no circumstances am i put seconds into a square shape at all!  You asked the question of how would one multiply a meter into another meter, or a second into another second, but that is exactly what i am asking!  I am told that i need not worry about this, but this contradicts my stated axiom, that these units must be of physical consequence.  And i am willing to stand by my axiom.

Comment: But, aren't parallel vectors of equal lengths are equivalent, but non-parallel vectors even of equal lengths are not?

Comment: _It surely must be a misnomer that we say seconds sqaured, because under no circumstances am i put seconds into a square shape at all!_ What does this even mean? _And i am willing to stand by my axiom._ Then you are not willing to learn. You are incorrect about many things you stated, but if you are adamant that you are right and the world is wrong, there is nothing we can do.

Comment: @MouazNachawati It is not a misnomer.  Multiplying units together doesn't mean organizing them into a shape.  If you're concerned with s$^2$, why aren't you concerned with kg m/s?  As far as your "axiom" goes, I'm afraid it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @J.Murray At first, a kg x a m was my first concern, but i had trouble visualizing it, so i decided to go with something more visually appealing, hence the meter-length x the meter-length question!

Comment: @Drjh If i were to ask you to multiply a second into a second, what is the result?  How can i conceptualize this result?  I came to this website because i have a strong desire to learn.  Prior to asking this question, my search has yielded zero satisfactory answers, because i am told to precisely ignore the result!  This goes against every instinct in my body as a student of physics!

Comment: @MouazNachawati You are under the impression that when we multiply units together, we are arranging them into some kind of shape which we could visualize.  This is **not what is happening**, but until you are willing to accept the possibility that you are wrong, there's nothing we can do to help you.  Without further context, multiplying a second by a second doesn't mean **anything**, just as multiplying a meter by a meter doesn't mean anything.

Comment: _If i were to ask you to multiply a second into a second_. You would get $s^2$ if you multiply a time (that uses seconds) BY (not into) by another time as if they are lengths, but the question is, why? What physical example requires you to do this? I will tell you: Absolutely NOTHING!

Comment: @MouazNachawati You are assuming that there is a direct, unambiguous physical interpretation for every possible combination of units, and that's simply wrong.  I'm afraid there's no deeper answer than that.

Comment: @J.Murray Yes, i am indeed assuming that there is a physical interpretation behind the units, at least the ones we use.  I have recently restarted learning all the physics i learned in college, and this issue always bothered me.  And i am afraid that the answer provided today still is unsatisfactory to me.  We are dealing with physics after all!  Thank you, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In general it makes no sense to ask what a unit means without context. It is like asking how an English letter is pronounced, the context matters and without the context there is no sensible answer.

> A meter lengthwise multiplied into a meter widthwise will undoubtedly form a square, each of sides one meter.
>
> But, what happens when you multiply a meter lengthwise times a meter lengthwise?

When you assign a direction to a quantity then you are talking about vectors. With vectors there is more than one way to calculate a product. The one that you are describing in the first quoted section is the cross product which can be used in the context of calculating an area of the square you described above.

The cross product has the geometric interpretation as the area of the parallelogram formed by the two vectors and points in the direction normal to the parallelogram (in the direction determined by the right hand rule). So $(1\text{ m},0,0)\times (0,1\text{ m},0)=(0,0,1\text{ m}^2)$ gives a 1 square meter square whose normal is along the z axis.

Similarly, in the same context $(1\text{ m},0,0)\times (1\text{ m},0,0)=(0,0,0)\text{ m}^2$. With the two sides of the parallelogram together the area is 0. Any other answer would involve a change of context.

> The most obvious one being that the units of torque are unequal in value to the units of energy.

The units are the same in the SI system, but the quantities are different. Torque is a vector and energy is a scalar. Torque is formed using a cross product and in cases where energy is the product of two vectors then it is the dot product.

Note, even if you take the magnitude of the torque such that they have the same units and are both scalars, they still have different meanings because they come from different contexts. This is a prime example of how essential the context is.

Comment: The quantities of torque and energy are different, but the units are different, too.  Your use of the vector product helps clarify this for me.  While i understand that the area of a (1 m, 0, 0) x (1 m, 0, 0) is zero, it still must have nonzero value, in some other way.  That 'other way' is what i am confused about.  Said another way, i can see that a row of 3 x a column of 3 gives me a square of value 9, but, i need not take powers of 3 in this context alone.  Lest i be stuck at cubing 3, and never permitting myself to finding 3^4 or those of higher powers.

Comment: @MouazNachawati said “While i understand that the area of a (1 m, 0, 0) x (1 m, 0, 0) is zero, it still must have nonzero value, in some other way.” That doesn’t make any sense. Either it is zero or non-zero. It can’t be both. You also said “The quantities of torque and energy are different, but the units are different, too”. As I said in the answer, not in SI units. The SI does not distinguish between your m(lw) and m(ww). In fact, any such embellishments to the units is expressly forbidden by the BIPM. See section 5.3.2 https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf

Comment: _The quantities of torque and energy are different, but the units are different, too_. They most certainly are NOT. You did college physics? I would seriously think about suing them.

Comment: @Drjh Actually, i was thinking about doing just that, because i was told that a s^2 has no physical meaning.  Now, you told me this exact same thing, but i am not paying you.  I did pay them.  A hefty amount, too.

Comment: No, what I said was using seconds as if they were physical like length and width is meaningless. Good luck with your studies and pending litigation.

Comment: Well, you said, and i quote, "absolutely NOTHING."  I came onto here for help.  Yet you arrogantly accused me of an unwillingness to learn because i wanted physical significance behind the things we do in physics.  You could have at least replied, "I don't know of any physical significance behind s^2."

Comment: Read my comment again. Then again. And again. And several times more.

Comment: I prefer to avoid incorrect information information, but thank you for the offer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident that I understand your question, but if you think of the tangent bundle to a line, then the fiber at each point is another line, which it's natural to conceptualize as pointing in the same direction as the base line itself.

In other words, a tangent vector to the line consists of a point $x$ on the line together with a point on another line (the line of tangent vectors based at $x$) pointing on the same direction.  That vector is characterized by a distance times a distance, both of which you can think of as "lengthwise".